# Why are cylinder sets constructed this way?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I read that given $\Omega = \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$, where $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are sets, the smallest $\sigma$-field generated by rectangles $A =  A_1 \times A_2$, where $A_1$ is an interval over $\Omega_1$ and $A_2$ is an interval over $\Omega_2$ can also be generated by 'cylinder sets', i.e.

$$C_1 = \{ A_1 \times \Omega_2\}$$

$$C_2 = \{ \Omega_1 \times A_2 \}$$

such that the $\sigma$-field over $\Omega$ generated by $C_1 \cup C_2$ is the same $\sigma$-field generated by $A$. My question is why couldn't we have the following set as a basis:

$$C^* = \{ \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2 \}$$

How does the $\sigma$-field generated by the one above differ from that of $A$ ?... Is the $\sigma$-field generated by $C^*$ still Lebesgue-measurable?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a typo, but the sigma-algebra generated by $C^*$ above is the trivial sigma-algebra. Did you mean,

$$C^* = \{A_1\times A_2\},$$

Where $A_1$ is an interval over $\Omega_1$ and $A_2$ is an interval over $\Omega_2$? In that case, you're right. The two sigma-algebras are equivalent. The standard convention of using $C_1$ and $C_2$ is used because it looks similar to the cylinder sets used for infinite-dimensional product spaces.

Comment: I think the problem is that the $\sigma$-field generated by that one set is very small, too small to be useful.

Comment: I meant $C^*=\{ \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2 \}$ , where $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are the set elements themselves (not intervals)... but yes i think that the $\sigma$-field generated by $C^*$ may be too small..